# Is there any sample codes for creating plugin, bundle, defining activity in NODEJS? using forge design automation api

Tags: forge, autodesk-designautomation

Currently im working on a web-application which will modify revit model parameters. but stuck at the plugin creation most of the examples are in .net, and im not working with it. so need NODEJS sample code for plugin, bundle and activity creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the plugins themselves would have to be written in .NET.

For the rest of the workflow (upload bundle, define activity and execute workitem) see code sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-nodejs-revit.window.family.create) and [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-custom-data-viewer) in Node.js.

Comment: thanks @BryanHuang for your help and quick response.

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at [forge-cli-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils), it includes a sample Node.js script for [setting up](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils/blob/develop/examples/inventor-thumbnail/setup-pipeline.js) and [running](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-cli-utils/blob/develop/examples/inventor-thumbnail/run-pipeline.js) a DA pipeline.